# Handle Modal Bottom Sheet on Foldable Phone

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, foldable-devices

Why `showModalBottomSheet` not full width in vertical fold display?
It also not full height in horizontal fold display, it will show the bottomSheet from center to top.Looks like the 'fold' limit its width/height

```
showModal(context, size) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        enableDrag: true,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
        ),
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: size.height * 0.8,
            width: size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
              ),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(),
          );
        });
  }
```

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModal(context, size);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Show Modal',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ))
```

[image: Modal Bottom Sheet on Vertical Fold Display]

Comment: I'm not running it yet on physical device, due to limitations of the device. I wonder if this still exist on physical device or not.